# Como Hago para Mostar un Valor en un Textbox al Seleccionar una Opción en un en un ComboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

A continuación tengo el siguiente problema es decir de un combobox que tiene 2 opciones quisiera que al momento de seleccionar una de las opciones de mi combobox me genere un valor que sera una constante en un textbox

mi codigo de xaml es el siguiente

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Estado_de_aportacion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" FontSize="14"  IsEditable="True" 
        IsReadOnly="True" 
        Text="-- Seleccione una opción --" Grid.Column="1" Margin="82,76,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" >

        <ComboBoxItem Content="No Aportante"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Aportante"/>
      
    </ComboBox>
```

y el codigo de C# es el siguiente

```
     private void cmb_Estado_de_aportacion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmb_Estado_de_aportacion.SelectedItem.ToString() == "No Aportante")
        {
            txt_Valor_de_aportacion.Text = "0,00";
        }
        if (cmb_Estado_de_aportacion.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Aportante")
        {
            txt_Valor_de_aportacion.Text = "20,00";
        }
    }
```

el problema que existe como tal es que cuando selecciono una opcion del combobox y el valor de 20 o 0 no se llenan en el textbox no se en que parte del codigo estaria fallando

Comment: Cual es el error

Comment: el problema que existe como tal es que cuando selecciono una opcion del combobox y el valor de 20 o 0 no se llenan en el textbox no se en que parte del codigo estaria fallando

Comment: quita SelectedItem y pon Text, quedaria como cmb_Estado_de_aportacion.Text